# Dynamics AX 2009: How to FTP from a batch job on an AOS

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

After quite a few searches for ways to FTP files in AX, I was happy to discover the WinInet class, which is more or less just a wrapper for the .DLL of the same name.  I thought my problems were solved!  I was not aware, however, that the class had a **major Achilles heel** -- it doesn't run in batch (on a server).

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Specifically, I want to upload (FTP put) a file to another server in a server-run batch job (running as a service user with admin rights to the file in question).  Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another example of using .NET classes for FTP in [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/FtpWebRequest).  It is different enough from 10p's example code to take a look...

In my own experience I ended up writing and then calling a bat file from the command line to pass in ftp commands as we needed to use a special FTP client!  Here are two examples of using shell scripting - [Net Time](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Current_Time#Net_Time_.2FDomain_.28Shell_Scripting_via_System.Diagnostics.Process.29) && [Run a Process](https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/axtechnical/b/axilicious/archive/2010/04/06/x-43-43-run-a-process-with-user-credentials.aspx).

Comment: I've attempted to use the **Run a Process** approach, and while I can see everything working _more or less_, the FTP commands file works when run manually, but for some reason doesn't **PUT** files on the server when run in the batch. Adding the -g switch to the ftp client helped a little, but now it attempts to **PUT** the files on the server, but in the end, they end up as 0 byte files. _Weird_. These are great tricks to know however, but I think I'm going to have to try the .NET approach above and see how it goes. I'm going to owe you guys some beers by the time everything is resolved! :)

Comment: Nevermind, the Axaptapedia link is perfect! Thanks, ian_scho!

Answer (score 2):

Use .NET classes in AX, e.g. following code logs into the FTP server and renames the file there:

```
str ftpHostName = 'ftp.microsoft.com'; // without "ftp://", only name
str username    = 'myloginname';
str password    = 'mypassword';
str oldname     = 'oldfilename';
str newname     = 'newfilename';

System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket;
System.Net.Dns dns;
System.Net.IPHostEntry  hostEntry;
System.Net.IPAddress[] addresses;
System.Net.IPAddress    address;
System.Net.IPEndPoint endPoint;

void sendCommand(str _command)
{
    System.Text.Encoding ascii;
    System.Byte[] bytes;
    ;

    ascii = System.Text.Encoding::get_ASCII();
    bytes = ascii.GetBytes(_command + '\r\n');
    socket.Send(bytes, bytes.get_Length(), System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags::None);
}
;

socket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily::InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType::Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType::Tcp);
hostEntry = System.Net.Dns::GetHostEntry(ftpHostName);

addresses = hostEntry.get_AddressList();
address = addresses.GetValue(0);

info(address.ToString());

endPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(address, 21);
socket.Connect(endPoint);

sendCommand(strfmt("USER %1", username));
sendCommand(strfmt("PASS %1", password));
sendCommand(strfmt("RNFR %1", oldname));
sendCommand(strfmt("RNTO %1", newname));
```

This is just an example but feel free to use any standard FTP command slightly mpdifying this code. Let me know if the concept is unclear.

Comment: How much more difficult is it to implement (or add) example code for a PORT command to send a file? I'm wondering how to tell the server which local port I want to send the file on (is there a way to choose an available port, or are they shots in the dark?), and then how do I send the file? The files that I'm sending are small (~50k) ASCII encoded .CSV text files.