# How to send file to ftp from Axapta 2012?

Tags: ftp, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to send file to FTP using x++ code in Axapta 2012 .I didn't get any useful code.please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would do [the same as in AX2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810978/dynamics-ax-2009-how-to-ftp-from-a-batch-job-on-an-aos/7820619#7820619), and use the .NET framework.  Both answers in the link are 'correct'.

Comment: I have used the same code but its not working in axapta 2012. even not showing any error. running fine but not transfering any file

Comment: 1. Check by repeating the ftp command from a console, from the AX server, but with your user....  Assuming that you are running the code from the server!  2. Could be a permissions issue, where the job or class running the ftp commands via AX is either as the AX service account or via impersonation (the AX authenticated user who ejecuted the code).

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to just use a visual studio project--then integrate with any ftp library you would like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg889157.aspx